# Mock a super class method in Mockito before spying a child class

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class which I need to test.

```
public class Mockz extends AnotherClass{
    final MyOtherClass = getMyOtherClass(); // method in AnotherClass
    Integer num = 10;
    protected void method1(){
        System.out.println("in method 1");
    }

    protected void method2(){
        System.out.println("in method 1");
    }
}
```

And in my test class I have a method like ,

```
@Test
public testMethod1(){
    final Mockz mockz = Mockito.spy(new Mockz()); // line 1
    Mockito.when(mockz.method1()).thenReturn("Mocking method 1");
    System.out.println(mockz.method1());
}
```

I think I need to mock the `getMyOtherClass()` method in the super class, Since when executing `line 1` that method gets called.

how can I do that ? Or what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: I would use constructor injection in order to initialize your `MyOtherClass myOtherClass` field rather than using a method. In case the parameter is not send or the parameter is null, then you will recur to your method to initialize this field.

Comment: You mean `MyOtherClass` object is used inside `method1()`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza `getMyOtherClass()` will return a `MyOtherClass ` object and in that method there are some logic to do with that object. after that the object is returned. So using a constructor is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a problem of class structure: You shouldn't need to (or want to) mock a superclass. When testing, you should test the entirety of your subclass (Mockz), even the parts that apply to the superclass (AnotherClass); otherwise, how would you know that the subclass is fulfilling the entirety of the superclass's contract?

If you're looking to refactor, you may consider switching to a composition/delegate pattern:

```
public class Mockz implements AnotherInterface {
  private final AnotherClass delegate;

  public Mockz() { this(new AnotherClass()); }

  /** for testing */
  Mockz(AnotherClass delegate) { this.delegate = delegate; }

  // ...
}
```

...or consider testing a subclass of your subclass:

```
@Test
public testMethod1(){
    final Mockz mockz = Mockito.spy(new Mockz() {
      @Override public OtherClass getMyOtherClass() {}
    });
    Mockito.when(mockz.method1()).thenReturn("Mocking method 1");
    System.out.println(mockz.method1());
}
```

...but that second one implies that `getMyOtherClass` is dangerous enough to warrant mocking, which probably means it shouldn't be a part of your object's constructor code path anyway, leading to the third answer: Don't call a "heavy-lifting" method on your initialization path:

```
public class Mockz extends AnotherClass{
    MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

    /** Part of construction, but expensive enough to call explicitly. */
    void initializeMyOtherClass() {
        myOtherClass = getMyOtherClass();
    }
}
```